# Android 3.0, Widget Preview

Tags: android, widget, thumbnails, preview, android-3.0-honeycomb

In Honeycomb some of the System apps have a "preview" of the widget when you click the "add" options on the home screen.

How do I go about adding a thumbnail/preview of my widget to my application so the user can get a feel for what it looks like when adding it in Honeycomb?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you run the android emulator against the Honeycomb sdk, you should see an app called Widget Preview, which will allow you to pick the widget to take a preview of (you will have to install your widget on the emulated device).  I think you can also build it yourself if you have the source checked out (it's under development/apps/WidgetPreview).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#preview

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer, I found it elsewhere before coming back here but this deserves acceptance non the less as it is correct.