# How to change widget launcher preview?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, launcher

I am creating a widget, and I want that in the launcher, the preview of my widget will not be just my app icon.

for example:

[image]

The contacs widgets are just the application icons, but the calendar widget is not.

How can I set my own image for this launcher preview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"` on the widget_info.xml

Answer (score 1):

Also create widget preview - follow this link

[Android 3.0 - Create Widget Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876628/android-3-0-widget-preview)